# VS2010 import/export setting does not work

Tags: visual-studio-2010, import, settings

I am trying to change the colors of my VS2010 according to the **color scheme** http://studiostyl.es/schemes/son-of-obsidian.

In order to import the setting, I go from Visual Studio menu to:

**Tools**  -> **Import and Export Settings** -> **Import selected environment settings**
-> **No, just import new settings, overwriting my current settings** 
-> **Choose settings to import** -> **All Settings**

I tried with both project closed and open but it does not work at all. Anybody might help?

Comment: At what point did you click the Browse button?

Comment: thanks. When I have the window *choose a collection of settings to import*. I select the setting file and i choose to import it

Answer (score 2):

A few possible solutions, try them in order:

1. First try to ONLY import Options/Environments/Fonts and Colors.
2. If you have ReSharper, disable Color identifiers which mess up most color schemes. Go to ReSharper Options/Code Inspection/Settings and disable Color identifiers.
3. Start RegEdit and first export a backup, then delete the keys below:
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\FontAndColors\
   Especially cache and the GUID. Then start VS and try import again. This worked for me.
4. I haven't even tried this but as a last resort, take a backup of C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings
   and then edit this file, removing the entire tag

Answer (score 1):

this solution works for me:

1. first of all download load your settings file
2. close visual studio
3. goto vs settings path . for me is "c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2010\Settings"
4. paste setting file
5. backup current setting (copy to another folder or ...)
6. rename your setting file to "CurrentSettings.vssettings"
7. open vs